# How can I strip off all non-numeric characters in a Pandas Series

Tags: python, string, pandas, split, data-manipulation

I have a Pandas DataFrame. And I am interested in getting a particular column with only numeric characters.

For example, the column contains rows like this:

```
4'> delay trip
4/
4'>book flight 'trip
34
4"> book flight delay
4"
```

How can I strip off all non-numeric characters and have just numeric characters like this:

```
4
4
4
[3,4]
4
4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove all non-numeric characters from all the values in a particular column in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117326/how-can-i-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-from-all-the-values-in-a-particular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 different problems here:

- first is to extract digits from the column cells
- second is to make a list if you have more than one digit

Just chain both operations:

```
df[col].str.findall(r'\d').apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) == 1 else '' if len(x) == 0 else x)
```

With you example it gives:

```
0         4
1         4
2         4
3    [3, 4]
4         4
5         4
```